# C# tag doesn't automatically color my sourcecode

Tags: feature-request

I noticed that sourcecode in SO only gets properly colored in if the C# tag is applied, and that feature doesn't seem to work (at least in [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1828/when-does-one-need-to-be-concerned-with-leaking-timing-information-in-net) question).

How can we get color coding to work?

... Should we (I think the answer is yes...)?

Comment: Not quite getting this question - what colours are you after? None of the tools I use colour source code - so I'm guessing I'm missing a trick?

Comment: In StackOverflow, all one needs to do is reference the C# tag (as a question metatag) and embedded source code is colored automatically.  This is not the case for security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

<strike>There are still some features of the sites that are currently in SO only.

As far as I know, syntax highlighting for sourcecode is one of them.</strike>

Turns out I was wrong:
[Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting)

Let's see if we can get some attention here...

Answer (score 0):

[As noted by @AviD](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting), syntax highlighting is being handled by [Google Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify) though I don't see any of the `.js` files included for SECSE. When visiting Stack Overflow, `prettify-full.en.js` gets downloaded and handles the syntax highlighting. Granted we're not as code heavy as SO but there are times when this would be useful. I've verified that ServerFault and Unix/Linux also use prettify.

Would like to know why SECSE still doesn't use [Google Prettify](https://github.com/google/code-prettify).

Comment: Short version is our dev team is fanatical about performance and never enables anything without proof that it's needed. On this site, we think prettify might enhance a few posts, but probably not most, and not enough to justify including it. If you think we're underestimating the value of prettification or amount of posts that would be enhanced, feel free to open a new meta question with some numbers/examples.